# My Question Has a Negative Score and No Answers, Should I delete it?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

Lets say that I have asked a poor question that cannot be improved by editing (there is something fundamentally wrong with the question). It has received a negative score and no answers after a few months. It clearly does not add anything to the community, so what is the best practice in handling its removal?

Should I take it upon myself to delete it, wait for it to be deleted by the community (i.e. a moderator or have people with high enough reputation vote to delete it) or wait until the [community user clean up scripts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) run? The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) says that the questions may be removed by either means, but is there an advantage to any of these options over the others? Which should be used?

Comment: The real question is how self-deletion will differ from community deletion regarding your overall question score and eventually contributes for a question-ban. I don't think there's a difference regarding this.

Comment: if I were in that situation, I would delete it to avoid the situation getting worse than it already is (receiving more downvotes.) This all assuming the question is not salvageable.

Comment: You get a badge if you delete it yourself.  Badges encourage good practices.

Comment: haha, I lolled at @HansPassant 's answer. Badges, badges, badges....

Comment: Just because your question has some downs doesn't mean it was a bad question.  Let's be real here for a minute.  In certain industries - specifically data science - there's lots of arrogance and 'better than you' snobs. If you ask those types of questions, they attract those types of people - which is especially bad for beginners trying to learn.  Their arrogance discourages openness to ask questions.

Comment: That is true in almost all fields, but the assumption here is that the question is bad and can not (or will not) be saved. So, in what manner should it be deleted?

Comment: Don't even bother lol, knowing S/O if you get more than 2 downvotes in the first few minutes of your question, you will be followed by 20 close votes and the question will be put [on hold] within 5 minutes.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Do you personally think that the question is valuable (even if some others don't)?  Do you think that other people, if they come across your question, will be glad that they did?  Does it make the internet a better place?

If so, don't delete the question.  If the community feels that your question isn't valuable and deletes it (either manually or automatically) then that's fine.  You thought it was useful and it wasn't; learn from it and do better next time.  If nothing else, keep the question around until you can figure out *why* people don't think that it's a useful question.  If you delete the question before learning what you did wrong, you're just going to make the same mistake again later.  If/when you figure out what you did wrong, *then* you can delete the question.

If you answered no to all of those questions at the top of my answer, and you really do recognize that your question isn't useful on this site, then you should delete it.  There's no point in wasting other people's time/effort on a question that nobody has faith in.

Comment: I would like to add this note :  Just because the community doesn't find it useful, does not mean that the question was not valid or served a purpose. This primarily (and possibly *only*) means that it is not a question that the community wished to accept into the system.

Comment: Regardless of this specific question, just because two/three people downvoted a question, you can hardly call it "*the community*". Pretty much anyone can downvote- you don't need to work hard for that privilege. Also, many questions are useful for people world wide which aren't registered users and hence don't vote or different users who don't bother to vote. Only if a question is heavily downvoted closed within few minutes or even deleted, you can pretty much conclude that at least 5 professionals (relatively high reps on this tag) concluded your question isn't useful.

Answer (score 4):

SO isn't automated, people aren't robots and not everyone follows guidlines for voting strictly. People can downvote by simply pressing down,  even when it's not appropriate and you didn't do anything wrong objectively. You shouldn't be intimidated by 1-2 downvotes and you definitly shouldn't delete your question immediatly.

First, read your question and look if what you wrote makes grammatical/syntactical sense to someone who isn't working with you. Make sure you have no big spelling errors that make the question hard to understand.
Improve formating to speed up skimming through your question, badly formatted questions that seem to ask about trivial topics can get downvotes if there is to much text in an unstructured way. Avoid making your question a big blob of text, paragraphs where invented for a reason. Structure your question to atleast 3 paragraphs if you have a big blob of text:

1. What problem did you encounter ?
2. (What did you try ?)
3. A definitly answerable question.
4. (Some code if neccessary)

Before you ask questions make sure to google what you are asking, not word by word, but something like "fortran stoud performance" should do, if you don't find anything useful after a handful of google searches with different wording then you can ask here.

Ask for feedback on downvotes if you don't know what's wrong but you want to improve and have readable english, that is more than most people who ask questions bad questions on SO do. But don't be desperate and emotional.

Also be aware that deleted questions and dowvotes on questions can result in a question ban, so you should be cautious with deleting your own questions, instead try to improve them as good as possible and let it sit there for 30 days, maybe someone will find the question or it's answers useful in that time, and if not the question will be deleted anyway.

Also undeleting questions isn't always possible and asking the same question twice will just lead you to a faster question ban, be aware of that. Only delete questions when you are 100% sure it's doesn't belong on SO.